# C: Same chars from two strings

Tags: c, algorithm

I have two strings:

```
char *str1 = "this is a test";
char *str2 = "ts bd a";
```

I'm trying to write a function that returns a new string with the same chars from the two string without duplicates (also ' ' is duplicate). eg.:

```
char *retStr = GetSameChars(str1, str2); //returns "ts a";
```

How can I do that?

What I'm tried:

```
char *GetSameChars(char str1[], char str2[]) {
    int found = -1, i , j = 0, biggest, index = 0;
    char *retArr, *star = '*';
    int str1Len, str2Len, count = 0;
    str1Len = strlen(str1);
    str2Len = strlen(str2);
    biggest = str1Len > str2Len ? str1Len : str2Len;

    retArr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * count);

    for (i = 0; i < str1Len; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < str2Len; j++) {
            if (str1[i] == str2[j] && found == -1) {
                count++;
                found = j;
            } else
            if (str2[j] == str2[found])
                str2[j] = star; //Throw an exception
        }
        found = -1;
    }

    retArr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * count);
    j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < str2Len; i++)
        if (str2[i] != '*')
            retArr[j++] = str2[i];

    for (i = 0; i < str2Len; i++)
        printf("%c", retArr[i]);
}
```

When I tried the line `str2[j] = star;` I got an exception.

What is my mistake?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do your code work, or not work? When you call your function what is the result of it? What result did you expect? And most importantly, *can you show the code of your function*? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, See update.

Comment: I imagine your compiler should be complaining at the `str2[j] = star;` line. You're trying to assign a `char*` type to a `char` type. `star` is just a single character, change its definition to `char star = '*';`

Comment: `str2[j] = star;` : You are trying to change the string literal.  **String literal must not be changed**. also perhaps `*star = '*'` --> `star = '*'`

Comment: `char *star = '*';` is not valid C and should be giving you a nasty warning. In general you should compile with all warnings enabled (`-Wall` if gcc or clang, `/W4` if microsoft), and then fix all the warnings. If you need help fixing warnings, post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that has the warning, and post the full exact warning message that the compiler generates.

Comment: I'm trying now to change to char str = '*' but its still not working

Comment: BTW, I would use an array `int used[256];` to keep track of which characters have already been seen.

Comment: ... along with *`unsigned`* `char` to keep that index positive.

Comment: That code should give you a compiler warning when you don't return anything from the function. You also call `malloc` with a zero `count` for some reason. There are probably many other problems (do you terminate the destination string?). And once you return a valid pointer then remember that you need to `free` it.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendations would be: keep it simple; get to know the C standard library; write less, test more.

Some specific problems with your code: you pass the wrong variable to `malloc()`; you estimate the answer to fit in the size of the larger of the two strings but it will actually fit into the smaller of the two; you modify an argument string `str2[j] = star` -- you should be treating the arguments as readonly; you `malloc()` `retArr` twice unnecessarily, leaking the first one when you allocate the second; your algorithm simply doesn't work.

Although a lookup table, as others have suggested, would be more efficient, let's use the standard library routine `strchr()` to solve this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getSameChars(const char *string1, const char *string2) {

    size_t string1_length = strlen(string1);
    size_t string2_length = strlen(string2);
    size_t shortest = string1_length < string2_length ? string1_length : string2_length;

    char *common_pointer, *common = malloc(shortest + 1);

    *(common_pointer = common) = '\0';

    for (size_t i = 0; i < string1_length; i++) {
        // character found in both input strings, but not yet in common string
        if (strchr(string2, string1[i]) != NULL && strchr(common, string1[i]) == NULL) {
            *common_pointer++ = string1[i];
            *common_pointer = '\0';
        }
    }

    return common;
}

int main() {
    char *stringA = "this is a test";
    char *stringB = "ts bd a";

    char *result = getSameChars(stringA, stringB);

    printf("%s\n", result);

    free(result);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `index` isn't a function of the standard library of C. use `strchr` instead of `index`.

Comment: Thank you @BLUEPIXY, I appreciate your correction and it's irony.

Answer (score 0):

Your code complains because you are trying to assign a pointer to a char, to get the value inside a pointer you need to use the * operator like so:

```
*star;
```

a good way to check if a letter have already appeared(if you want to use it on all of the ascii table then 128) is to use a lookup table. first you will need to declare an array the length of all letters in the alphabet like so:

```
char lut[26];
```

If it is a global variable then it will be set to 0, then all you need to do is go to the index of the char you got and mark it as 1, a simple if will later be able to determine if a letter has already appeard. 
example:

```
lut[toupper(somechar) - 'A'] = 1;
```

In this example you set the char in the lookup table that is equivalent to the somechar variable as 1, marking it has already appeared.

hope this helps.